# After changing WordPress Address (URL) blogs are not displayed

Tags: wordpress, url

I changed the WordPress Address (URL) and Site Address (URL) from
http://xx-stage.xxxxx.com/resources
to 
http://xx-stage.xxxxx.com/home
for making static page as a front page. I have selected Blogs as a post page.
After doing this change i am not able to see blogs.
I am able to see static front page but not blogs or other pages.
It's on a staging server.
Please help.

TIA

Comment: Did you change the WP setting for use blog page as front page to use static page as front page? Site Address should probably be http://xx-stage.xxxxx.com/

Comment: It's nothing but setting issue from dashboard.

Comment: @Kallmanation -I tried this but it takes me to Index Directory structure instead of login page.

Comment: Well regardless... changing your site url is not the proper way to change your home page. You have to use the setting I mentioned